# PHP redirect user another page in a downloaded Ajax XmlHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, redirect, xmlhttprequest

I have a login page. When the user enters username, password, and click the LogIn button, the button calls an Ajax XmlHttpRequest, which send the username and password to the process.php. The php process the data, and return if username or password is not correct. But when correct, I want to redirect the user to the session.php. Php header doesn't work because it takes the page code, and JavaScript doesn't work too, because doesn't run the code. How can I do it?

Here is the Ajax:

```
function logIn() {
    var loader = document.getElementById('loaderParent');
    var form = document.getElementById('formI');
    form.style.display = "none";
    loader.style.display = "block";
    setTimeout(function() {
      var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
      var username = document.getElementById('username').value;
      var password = document.getElementById('password').value;
      xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        // console.log(4);
          document.getElementById("form").innerHTML =
          this.responseText;
        }
      };
      xhttp.open("POST", "class/process.php", true);
      xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
      xhttp.send("zone=LogIn&section=2&username="+username+"&password="+password);
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: Show your code....

Comment: We're going to need to see your code, but the upshot is that you have to perform the redirect using JavaScript in the success callback of your AJAX function.

Comment: I attached the code

Answer (score 0):

what you need is a javascript redirect. For example, use this to redirect to Google main page:

```
location.href = 'http://www.google.com';
```

By the way, I recommended you use a library like JQuery to simplify your Ajax call.